# Luego de tomar una foto Camera.TakePhoto() no funciona la inicialización de variables

Tags: android, genexus

En un evento al utilizar la función `Camera.TakePhoto()`, al retornar de tomar la foto, y dentro del mismo evento, las variables que inicializo no toman el valor nuevo, continúan con el viejo.

Se tiene un botón X que llama al evento 'Procesar'.

Este evento verifica si el nombre del empleado (cargado antes) no es vacío. Si no lo es, procesa, luego se actualiza la variable `&EmployeeName = ''`

1. Si tomo la foto y luego de finalizar el evento, vuelvo a presionar el mismo botón, vuelve a entrar porque la variable `&EmployeeName` sigue cargada y no la actualizó.
2. Si no tomo la foto, al presionar el botón X, no procesa porque la variable `&EmployeeName` esta inicializada.

Ejemplo:

```
Event 'Procesar'
    composite
        If not &EmployeeName.IsEmpty()
            If &DeviceTakePhoto = 'S'
                Do 'TakePhoto'
                If &Image.IsEmpty()
                    msg('Debe tomar una foto!')
                    &HayFoto = 'N'
                Else
                    &HayFoto = 'S'
                EndIf
            EndIf
            If  ( (&DeviceTakePhoto = 'S' and &HayFoto <> 'N') or &DeviceTakePhoto <> 'S' )  
                &EmployeeName     = ''
            EndIf
        EndIf
    EndComposite            
EndEvent

Sub 'TakePhoto'
    &Image = Camera.TakePhoto()
EndSub
```

Dentro del 'Procesar' original, llamo a otros `procs()` que no cambian en nada la operativa, también funciona bien si obtengo la geolocalización.

Ya probé poner la llamada de `Camera.TakePhoto()` en el evento 'Procesar' y pasa lo mismo, de hecho, era como estaba siempre pero lo saqué para probar.

Answer (score 0):

Mauricio, estoy tratando de reproducir este problema sin éxito.

Aquí puedes encontrar el apk de ejemplo y se comporta como es esperado:

Apk:
http://apps5.genexus.com/Id09ca2f2c930605d40267ac204495c800/TestTakePhoto.apk

Xpz:
http://apps5.genexus.com/Id09ca2f2c930605d40267ac204495c800/gxmetadata/TestTakePhoto.xpz

Primer click toma la foto. Siguiente no lo hace porque ya hay una.

Estoy probando con Genexus v15 u7, Android 8.0.

Por favor , si este ejemplo no funciona en tu dispositivo enviame los datos del device.

Si funciona, envianos tu ejemplo para evaluar las diferencias y en que versión de Genexus lo estas haciendo.

Gracias,

Answer (score 0):

Tuve el mismo problema con dispositivos Samsung, concretamente con un S4 y un S8,instalando el preview de U9 me solicionó el problema.

Te paso el [SAC #42769: Imagen tomada desde algunos dispositivos Android queda vacía y no presenta error.](https://www.genexus.com/es/developers/rn?data=42769;4;v15;8;9;;)